How can I obtain and display the Album cover art image of an mp3 file in React js?
I am a beginner learning react, and recently ran into an issue while coding. I want to create a simple audio player app that can fetch mp3 files from a folder and play them, as well as display the current song cover art, just like they do in phones and PC music players. Is it possible to react? is there any underlying knowledge or package that can streamline this process?
I tried researching on id3 tags, audio elements in reacts, etc., but it's just not flowing yet

React.js is predominantly used for web applications, pair react with electron.js in order to create a desktop application.
